# Two column items with titles in a beamer

Tags: beamer

In the following image you can clearly see that the titles and the items are no aligned.

[image]

Here is the code for the above image,

```
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Applications of nanofluids}

\begin{columns}
  \column{0.5\textwidth}\centering
    {\bf{Heat Transfer Applications}}\\[.2cm]
    \begin{itemize}
    \item Industrial Cooling Applications
    \item Nuclear Reactors
    \item Extraction of Geothermal Power\\[.2cm]
    \end{itemize}
  \column{0.5\textwidth}\centering
    {\bf{Automotive Applications}}\\[.2cm]
    \begin{itemize}
    \item Nanoﬂuid Coolant
    \item Nanoﬂuid in Fuel
    \item Nanoﬂuid in Fuel\\[.2cm]
    \end{itemize}
\end{columns}
\begin{columns}
  \column{0.5\textwidth}\centering
    {\bf{Electronic Applications}}\\[.2cm]
    \begin{itemize}
    \item Cooling of Microchips
    \item  Microscale Fluidic Applications    
    \end{itemize}
  \column{0.5\textwidth}\centering
    {\bf{Biomedical Applications}}\\[.2cm]
    \begin{itemize}
    \item Nanodrug Delivery
    \item  Nanocryosurgery
    \end{itemize}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
```

Any suggestion to improve it and make it look better?

Comment: vertically? horizontally? how should they be aligned?

Comment: @samcarter both as well as there should be space between column 12 and column 34

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the titles in horizontal alignment I suggest using top aligned `columns` environments, for the vertical alignment remove the `\centering` and don't use `\bf`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Applications of nanofluids}

\begin{columns}[onlytextwidth,t]
    \begin{column}{0.48\textwidth}
        \textbf{Heat Transfer Applications}

    \begin{itemize}
        \item Industrial Cooling Applications
        \item Nuclear Reactors
        \item Extraction of Geothermal Power
    \end{itemize}
  \end{column}
  \begin{column}{0.48\textwidth}
    \textbf{Automotive Applications}

    \begin{itemize}
        \item Nanoﬂuid Coolant
        \item Nanoﬂuid in Fuel
        \item Nanoﬂuid in Fuel
    \end{itemize}
  \end{column}
\end{columns}

\bigskip
\begin{columns}[onlytextwidth,t]
 \begin{column}{0.48\textwidth}
    \textbf{Electronic Applications}

    \begin{itemize}
        \item Cooling of Microchips
        \item  Microscale Fluidic Applications    
    \end{itemize}
    \end{column}
  \begin{column}{0.48\textwidth}
    \textbf{Biomedical Applications}

    \begin{itemize}
        \item Nanodrug Delivery
        \item  Nanocryosurgery
    \end{itemize}
  \end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The only issue is not that I am having solid circles for items not the triangles you are having.

Comment: @zhk As you only posted a code fragment and no compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) I cannot know which theme etc. you are using, so I used the standard one.

Comment: How to add a fifth column just below column 34 and keep it in the center?

Comment: @zhk The same way you did with the previous columns (I don't know how your 34 numbering scheme works)

Comment: I did that, but its not in the center.

Comment: @zhk try `\begin{columns}[t]
 \begin{column}{0.48\textwidth}`